# Java - What does this expression mean?

Tags: java

What does the following expression mean in Java?

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

Is it the same as

```
Graphics2D g2 = new Graphics2D(g);
```

expression?

Comment: This does not compile. You missed the semicolons: `;`.

Comment: nope. it's a cast (probably a downcast).

Comment: First is a type cast, second a constructor with argument.

Comment: @AdamArold I did not upvote, but this is a 100% honest question from someone who is new to the language. The two declarations have the same thing on the left, so OP may get curious as to what's the difference. Please do not assume that everyone in the world has equal access to Java instructors at every level - you may be looking at a question from someone who is attempting Java by reading an intro book. In a sense, this site is their instructor.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - The top reason to downvote a question is 'this question does not show research effort' (from the tooltip on the downvote button). Which is quite clearly the case in this instance.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: "Does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Applies here.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not the same.

This expression is a so called *cast*. It takes the object `g` an casts it to the class `Graphics2D`.

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

This expression is an *instanciation*. It creates a new object of the class `Graphics2D`. To create this object, it passes another object to it (the object `g`).

```
Graphics2D g2 = new Graphics2D(g);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the two expressions are different.

- The first expression is a *cast*. Here is what you are telling the compiler: "I know that `g` at runtime is an instance of `Graphics2D`, but its statically declared type is different. Make me a new *variable* `g2` which references the same object as `g`, but has the static type of `Graphics2D`.
- The second expression is a `new` expression. It instructs the program to create a new object `Graphics2D`, and pass its constructor an object `g` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I Think that, on the first example you re Casting a g object to Graphics2D, on the second you re creating a new instance Graphics2D. i don´t how is the best way to do that.